# Obtain form input fields and insert them as variables

Tags: php, forms, variables, get

I have the form with below

Action :`<form action="https://www.site.ro/test/request.php" method="get">`

Fields1 :`<input type="text" class="input-text full-width" name="currency" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Oras sau regiune" />`

Field 2:`<input type="text" class="input-text full-width" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" />`
 etc

And i want to get all the data inputed from this form to request.php as variables
into

`$filters[] = array("filterType" => "Regiune", "filterValue" => "Data from field 1");`

and so on.

Is this posible ?

Comment: Please watch out tagging right. PHP is not PGP.

Answer (score 0):

This is posible and you can do it using get variable $_GET['here goes input field name'];